# ¿Como mostrar el contenido de un dato en especifico con php desde mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Estoy haciendo un sistema para notificaciones de bienvenida que se suben a una base de datos: txt_parrafo
Entonces lo que quiero hacer es que en mi pagina principal se muestre el texto con el id mas alto registrado en mi base de datos Ejemplo:

|id|Texto                       |
|1 |Bienvenido a esta pagina web|
|2 |Nuevo Producto: ""          |
|3 |No olvides ....             |

Entonces les muestro mi codigo y le explico como funciona

Un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer.

```html
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "despacho_edit_website_admin";

$table_user = "users";
$table_txt = "txt_parrafo";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db); //<-- Conectamos con la base de datos.//

$queryText = "SELECT Texto from txt_parrafo order by id desc limit 1"; //<-- Escribo la busqueda que voy a realizar, Segun yo aqui estoy diciendo que quiero la columna Texto de la fila con el id mas alto,//

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$queryText); //<--- y aqui obtengo el resultado de la busqueda.//


//Entonces Aquí ya no se que hacer para mostrar el texto que se encuentra en la base de datos.//

?>


<div class="txtnotification">

            <?php
                echo '<p>'.$resultado.'</p>';
            ?>

</div>
```

Aqui es cuando ya no se que hacer osea como lo muestro por que si coloco dentro de las etiquetas

la variable .$resultado. no aparece nada.
Espero me puedan decir que estoy haciendo mal o como arreglarlo

Comment: Creo que en alguna parte tienes que usar fetch en el lado de PHP,  o no se si estoy mal y fetch solo se usa si estuvieses usando PDO,  pero pues con mysqli no sabria decirte... creo que en si la consulta tiene problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Debes de procesar el resultado. Para ello usa la funcion mysqli_fetch_assoc(), en la cual le pasas por parámetro el resultado y vas procesando línea a línea, en la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) podrás encontrar ejemplos prácticos. Prueba el siguiente código:

```
<div class="txtnotification">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        echo $row['Texto'];
    }
    ?>
</div>
```